# ANCOVA with two (related) factors

Tags: r, repeated-measures, ancova, jasp

I'm analysing data from a repeated-measures study, in two participant groups (call them **patient** and **control** groups).

I have measured a dependent variable **response**. Both the patient and control groups received a range of quantifiable treatment doses at different times. Because **dose** is a continuous variable, I understand that I need to use ANCOVA, rather than a repeated measures ANOVA, to analyse the data (since repeated measures ANOVA would treat the different **dose**s as categorical data, not continuous).

So far so good. I am currently interested in finding out whether the between subjects factor "**control**/**patient**" affects the **response**. I can construct an ANCOVA with **dose** as a covariate, and **control**/**patient** as a fixed factor. However, since my data table is arranged in a *long* format (one observation per row), I need to tell the model to take into account the fact that multiple observations (i.e. at different **dose**s) come from the same participant. I can do this by adding **participant_id** into the model as a fixed factor. This is where I hit a problem: I cannot run my model because the coefficients **patient/control** and **participant_id** are aliased.

I'm doing this in both JASP and R (I tend to use both to double-check). I understand *why* the coefficients are aliased: any given **participant_id** only belongs to one group (**patient** or **control**). Not both. So JASP (and R) complain because they are trying to work out the relationship between these two variables. But, I don't care to know the relationship between the two, I only really care to know whether **control/patient** is affected, but I somehow need to tell the model to recognise that multiple observations come from the same observer.

I know I could restructure my data into a *wide* format (repeated measures on the same row), but then I couldn't run it as an ANCOVA in JASP (or, I think, R). So how do I avoid the error message about coefficient aliasing?

One other thing - there are equal numbers of observations from each participant. So perhaps I needn't worry at all about including **participant_id** in the model?

Comment: Why do you not consider the participant a random effect?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on my terminology, but I think I *do* consider it as a random effect. That's what is causing the aliasing with the **patient/control** coefficient.

Comment: could you add the exact model formula you used so far in R and the package/function you called?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I feel you should use Linear Mixed Models. As mentioned by @david, you can include both random and fixed effects into the model, hence the mixed model.

Comment: I think you're right – I should be using a Linear Mixed Model, with participant_is as a random effect. Happy to award the bounty to an answer...